# Determining the intersection point between 3 vectors.

Tags: calculus, vectors

I have four points in 2D, three known and one unknown. The unknown point is the point of intersection between the known vectors. The four points are $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, where $B$ is the origin $(0;0)$ and $D$ is the unknown point of intersection.

Vector **A** extends from $A$ to $D$. Vector **C** extends from $C$ to $D$, Vector **B** extends from $B$ to $D$.

The angles between **A,B** and **C** are known.

I am using the dot product equation: $A.B = |A| |B| \cos(\theta)$.

So essentially I have two equations and the $2$ unknowns: $x$ and $y$ coordinates of $D$.

$$|A.B| = |A|\,|B|\cos(\alpha)$$
$$|C.B| = |C|\,|B|\cos(\beta)$$

Is there a way to solve for the point $D$ in terms of the other points and the angle between their vectors?

Comment: I don't understand what is the intersection point of vectors.

Comment: It is the point in 2D space where the two vectors pass through one another ie, intersect.